# Enable and Disable Textboxes jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have enabled mutiple textboxes with jQuery. But I am not sure how to re-enable them if it the radio button is not selected. What modifications would I have to make to my current code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {      

    $(":radio[id^=check]").click(function() {
        var textId = "#" + this.id.replace("check", "text");
        $(textId).removeAttr("disabled", "disabled").css('background-color', '#99FF66')
    });

//alert("test");

});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure anyone knows what you really trying to do or asking.  Considering describing your scenario in more detail. I'm guessing once explaining what you are trying to do in a couple paragraphs someone will suggest how to solve it.

Comment: Okay, so currently I have mutiple radio buttons that relate to mutiple textboxes. The textboxes are all disabled to begin with. This code enables a certain textbox when a certain radio button is clicked. However, once the click the radio button and then unclick the radio button nothing happens it still stay enabled when it should disabled and revert back. So, my questions is. How do I disable the textbox when the radio button is not selected? Or when the select it and then un select it? Does that make sense? Sorry I was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single handler to do both -- disable when the radio button isn't checked, enable when it is.  Using @AlienWebGuy's observation that you can use the checked test for the value of the property, this can be done as:

```
$(":checkbox[id^=check]").click(function() {
    $("#" + this.id.replace("check", "text"))
        .prop("disabled", $(this).filter(':checked').length == 0);
});
```

when coupled with this CSS

```
<style>
   input:disabled {
       background-color: #99ff66;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Ideally he'd set CSS for `input:disabled{background-color:#99FF66;}` Then he could eliminate the condition like so: `$(text).prop('disabled',$(this).filter(':checked').length == 0);`

Comment: These work, but if you unselected the radio button it does not disable it again. Is it because I disable the textbox from the beginning? @AlienWebGuy

Comment: @Alex - here's a version with checkboxes (which should work) with the code as modified.  You can't really "uncheck" a solo radio button. http://jsfiddle.net/qfFCG/

Comment: @Alex - here's a version using a pair of radio buttons. http://jsfiddle.net/gdQZZ/

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$(textId).removeAttr("disabled", "disabled")` by  `$(textId).removeAttr("disabled")`

It is quite obvious if you read the docs, [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) doesn't take two arguments

Answer (score 0):

You want to manipulate the property, not the attribute:

`$(textId).prop('disabled',true);` and `$(textId).prop('disabled',false');`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete the task doing it this way. Baiscally, I have id on my textbox and radio buttons. That go radio button id="check1" textbox id="text1", radio button id="check2" textbox id="text2". Then in my decline id i have radio button id="checker1" and textbox id="text1", etc.

So based on which one the choose it will enable it and turn it green, or disable and turn it red.

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Goes through each and if click adds css and removes disable
    $(":radio[id^=check]").click(function() {
        var textId = "#" + this.id.replace("check", "text");
        $(textId).removeAttr("disabled").css('background-color', '#99FF66').css('color', '#000')
        });

    //Goes through each and if checked adds disabled and turns red 
    $(":radio[id^=checker]").click(function() {
        var textId = "#" + this.id.replace("checker", "text");
        $(textId).attr("disabled", "disabled").css('background-color', '#FF0033').css('color', '#FFFFFF')
    });

//alert("test");

});
</script>
```